# RVM and bash_profile

Tags: installation, rvm, bash

I'm having problems installing RVM on my mac. I took my computer in to have the fan repaired so I'm using my wives trying to set up my environment to get some work done.

The problem I'm having is the bash_profile. Every time I add the function:
**[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function**

and then reload the shell I get the following error:

**-bash: export: `-s': not a valid identifier
-bash: export:`/Users/Christine/.rvm/scripts/rvm': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `]]': not a valid identifier
Christines-MacBook:~ Christine$**

Here is my current environment:

- OSX Lion 10.7.2
- git version 1.7.5.4
- latest RVM is installed
- xcode version 4.2.1
- bash_profile:
  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How accurate is your final bullet point? That is, does your `bash_profile` say:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

or

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

They should be on separate lines, and based on your error message, I'd guess this is the problem.

Comment: Brandon, thanks for the reply. After searching around on my setup I found what you mentioned as part of my problem. The other problem was x-code 4.2 and rvm apparently that version of x-code causes problems with rvm. I found this http://www.andygoundry.com/2011/11/16/making-rvm-gemsets-work-under-os-x-lion-with-xcode-4-2/ as fix and it is now working. Thanks for the help!