# when i open a new tab on my mac terminal on mac, it displays unnecessary code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, terminal, rvm

when i open a new tab on my mac terminal, it displays unnecessary code.

This code is spitted on the terminal from the files which terminal loads when it starts,  like .profile, .bash_profile, .bash

Here is the code displayed when i open a new tab.

```
Last login: Mon Jan 16 15:00:48 on ttys002
-bash: export: `-s': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/jayparteek/.rvm/scripts/rvm': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `]]': not a valid identifier
-bash: /usr/local/bin[[: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/local/bin: is a directory
```

I know this is coming from either of the following files.

.bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 


alias gst='git status'
alias gl='git pull'
alias gp='git push'
alias gd='git diff | mate'
alias gc='git commit -v'
alias gca='git commit -v -a'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gba='git branch -a'

export EDITOR='mate -w'

alias mysql="/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql"
alias mysqld="sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM"


export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 


/usr/local/bin[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

.profile

```
export BUNDLER_EDITOR=mate


alias gco='git co'
alias gci='git ci'
alias grb='git rb'



export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Improved .bash_profile file

```
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm


alias gst='git status'
alias gl='git pull'
alias gp='git push'
alias gd='git diff | mate'
alias gc='git commit -v'
alias gca='git commit -v -a'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gba='git branch -a'

export EDITOR='mate -w'

alias mysql="/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql"
alias mysqld="sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM"


export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 


/usr/local/bin[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: More specifically, it's coming from the multiple instances of [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]] in .bash_profile

Comment: I removed the multiple instances & replaced it with  source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm. Then i restart the terminal, but the issue isn't resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from all of the repeated instances of `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in your bash profile.

Try replacing it with something simpler like `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

You definitely shouldn't have to do this multiple times, once should suffice. If it's not working, then you might want to look at some other answers for similar questions to see how they solved it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767135/rvm-and-bash-profile) was in the sidebar for this question when I loaded it.

Hope that helps.