# Installing Rails - It says I didn't even though I did

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, installation

I am trying to run a

```
rails new demo
```

But am told:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
$ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I run that command, and many 'fetching' lines followed by many 'Installing RDoc documentation for...' are run, but then the last lines say:

```
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.13...
file 'lib' not found
```

and then it stops running, and the 'rails' command (see above) doesn't work still. Why is Rails not installed? What else should I do? Thanks

Comment: did you installed rails on your machine.

Comment: I did, but apparently in the wrong place - see below, I just posted an answer, it works now

Comment: Lucy, probably you can use this bash script to install each and every possible tools needed for you to make a development environment up and running with rails: github.com/joshfng/railsready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it: apparently I was trying to install rails in the directory. I did the following and it worked well:

```
cd /
```

Then I ran

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Then I `cd` into the relevant directory again and now

```
rails new demo
```

worked!

Comment: without installing rails how `rails new demo` works..? i think first time you run `rails new demo` without installing  rails

Comment: Why the downvote? I explained here the answer - the initial problem was - it indeed wouldn't install since I tried installing in the wrong location

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is rdoc related. Short version, try :

```
gem install rdoc
```

And then launch the install of rails again.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129882/rails-3-install-error-file-not-found-lib) that seems to have helper a lot of people with this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to do a 'sudo gem install rails' since you may experience permission problems with your applications in the future.

I would recommend you using [RVM](http://rvm.io)  which is a ruby version manager. You can easily install different versions of Rubies, you can create application specific gemset's and minimize possible futuristic 'rails is not currently installed' errors.

I highly recommend you searching and reading about these concepts:

- RVM
- Gemsets
- .rvmrc
- .bashrc and .bash_profile

Comment: I also installed rvm, but I installed rails too. is that redundant?

Comment: Nope. Surely you're supposed to install Rails too. RVM is for installing Rubies and creating gemsets. Make sure you've added RVM to your PATH. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767135/rvm-and-bash-profile